# How does an onager work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

Basically, if you have a rod that rotating around a point due to torsion, such as that of an onager (roman catapult) and that rod is used to throw a projectile - a ball for example - what would be the formula that defines the force that is applied to the ball from the torque in the rod?

Comment: The sprung rod of an onager actually powered a sling, similar to a staff sling.

Comment: @AdrianHoward, I'm referring to the more simple, early design that didn't feature a sling

Comment: That should function as a class 3 lever, lever formulae can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever#Force_and_levers

Comment: Thank you! that helps a lot